# How to know the next point in the arc if we know the radius coordinate, first point on arc and angle of change between first and next point

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

How to know the next point in the arc if we know the radius coordinate, first point on arc and angle of change between first and next point ?

Let's suppose we have point first as (1117, 453), the radius coordinates as (720, 853) and angle of change between the next point and first point is 3.6 degrees.

What will be the coordinates of next point on the arc ?

I have calculated the radius with the formula attached [formula to find the length between two points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs02c.png)
The radius i got is approx 563.

I am expecting the formula to find the next point in the arc with 3.6 degree change in clockwise direction.

Comment: This question fits a lot better in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rotate point `(x0, y0)` about center `(cx, cy)` by angle `fi`. New coordinates are:

```
x = cx + (x0 - cx) * cos(fi) - (y0 - cy) * sin(fi)
y = cy + (x0 - cx) * sin(fi) + (y0 - cy) * cos(fi)
```

(dont't forget about degrees and radians)

Comment: Thanks for the solution i was working to get the coordinates for my canvas project after rotation of the image to get the points. :)

Comment: @PragyatSrivastava in that case you might be interested in DOMMatrix.transformPoint(), which will allow you to apply more complex transforms too.